# Rest API for- XML POST in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, rest

I have a problem regarding XML calling to REST web service, I have to pass the following parameters to my web services in the following format.

Request

```
<Registration>
<PhoneNumber>+919895191166</PhoneNumber>
<Age>25</Age>
</Registration>
```

So I write a code for this. But I didn't get any response. My sample code is below.

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL" ];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    
    //set headers
    NSString *accept = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/xml"];
    [request addValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml"];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    
    //create the body
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@" <Registration>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<PhoneNumber>%@</PhoneNumber>",@"xxxxxx"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@" <Age>%@</Age>",@"25"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</Registration>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    //post
    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
```

What is the reason for it? I made a mistake when I'm creating an XML request. Please help me to solve this? can you give me a code for this? I was fed up with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for my question

```
    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    
    NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
    
    NSString *rss=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
    
    if([urlResponse statusCode ]>=200 && [urlResponse statusCode]<300)
    {
          NSLog(@"Response:%@",rss);
    }
```